# iOS extend controller and miniplayer won't handle event using chromecast receiver based on shaka player

Tags: android, swift, chromecast, shaka

I'm using 
https://github.com/google/shaka-player/tree/master/demo/cast_receiver

with iOS client and android Client.
My iOS it's base on:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

With Android there is no problem doing seek, pause, play on miniplayer or extended controller provided from google, when a i cast a video on shaka player receiver.

In iOS i receive this messages:

> -[GCKMediaControlChannel mediaSessionID]  Calling a method that requires a media status with no media status, ignoring; make sure that
>   media is loaded, the media channel has received a status, and that
>   this method is not being called while the device manager is attempting
>   to reconnect

and other logs:

> -[GCKUIMediaController updateTransportControls]  updateTransportControls; mediaclient is , mediaStatus is ,
>   _currentRequest is 
>   -[GCKUIMediaController request:didFailWithError:]  request 15 failed with error Error Domain=com.google.GCKError Code=32 "No media session
>   is available" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No media session is
>   available}

Comment: Did you manage to fix it by any chance?